# Is there a way to insert live chat messages on behalf of oauth authenticated users?

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I have an oauth app so users can authenticate their youtube account. I would like to be able to insert live chat messages on their behalf. I have attempted to submit live chat messages to the API using the authentication tokens for the users but it still shows the author of the message as my app. Is there a way to insert live chat messages on behalf of oauth authenticated users?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/insert

**Note:** I am posting this question here based on the instructions for youtube live api support found here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/support

Answer (score 0):

After stepping away from this problem for a bit and returning to it I came to find that the API does post chat messages on behalf of the user when using their oauth tokens. My problem was in my application. I was not including `access_type=offline` in the url when authenticating the user. Without this parameter there is no `refresh_token` retrieved. My application logic was falling back to default tokens when the refresh token was not retrieved.